# problems with restarting countdown

Tags: android, flutter, dart, timer

i am trying to make it so that when the timer finishes, it automatically restarts but it seems i am running into some problems. here is the code

```
int _start = 7;
  int? selectedValue;


  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
          (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {});
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
  void restartTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
   setState(() {
     _start = 5;
   });
    startTimer();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    startTimer();
    restartTimer();
```

i would appreciate a fix to this problem

Comment: are you calling both `restartTimer` and  `startTimer` inside `initState`?

Comment: yes. i want to start the timer then when it is complete, restart it

Comment: You can cancel the timer inside `if (_start == 0) { _timer?.cancel(); _start = 5;setState(() {})`

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `restartTimer()` after the timer reaches zero

```
if (_start == 0) {
    setState(() {});
    restartTimer();
}
```

I would also suggest allowing zero and restarting after

```
if (_start < 0) {
    restartTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could send the whole snippet it may be easier to see what is wrong but from what I can already see, you put the restart timer method in the initState, which means, the method will be called only once and at the wrong time.

What I would suggest is:

```
     int _start = 7;
      int? selectedValue;
    
    
      void startTimer() {
        const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
        _timer = Timer.periodic(
          oneSec,
              (Timer timer) {
            if (_start == 0) {
              setState(() {
                restartTimer();
              });
            } else {
              setState(() {
                _start--;
              });
            }
          },
        );
      }
      void restartTimer() {
        if (_timer != null) {
          _timer.cancel();
        }
       setState(() {
     _start = 5;
   });
    startTimer();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    startTimer();
```

Here I took away the restart timer method and put it inside your start method where you check if the countdown is 0 or not.
Don't forget to not put the int _start = 7 into the build, else when you will set the state again, the "start" will be 7 instead of 5 as you intended in your method (and the _start-- won't work either).

Hope it helped.